# Создание панельки выбора файла

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: пример панельки]

Возможно ли создать средствами winforms создать сию панельку?
ListBox,ListView приспособить не получилось...

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: В смысле? С ListBox'ом?

Comment: Да c ListBox...

Comment: Не получилось сделать отображение бокса поверх всей программы, выбор файла по наведению,возможнгость изменения размера сей панельки

Comment: Отображение бокса поверх всей программы: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833961/show-listbox-outside-of-form-winforms - Show listbox outside of form (winforms)

Comment: Остальные проблемы думаю тоже решаемые.

Comment: @cpp_user, в подходе проблема. Не надо делать это руками.

Comment: @Qwertiy: не всегда стандартного поведения достаточно.

Comment: А чем вам старый добрый комбобокс не угодил?

Comment: @VladD, с использованием свойств, написанных ниже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте у TextBox свойства [AutoCompleteMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), AutoCompleteCustomSource и AutoCompleteSource. Примеры кода есть в описании.

Answer (score 0):

Это вообще не так надо делать.

Для автодополнения путей нужно взять обычный TextBox и применить к нему функцию `SHAutoComplete`. Ниже пример на VB.NET, на C# аналогично.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Declare Function SHAutoComplete Lib "Shlwapi.dll" (ByVal hWndEdit As IntPtr, ByVal dwFlags As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  SHAutoComplete(TxtTest.Handle, 0)
End Sub

End Class
```